# Upgrade to Sharepoint 2010 - Project Tracking & IT Team Workspaces not recognized

Tags: templates, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-upgrade

I have a WSS 3 SP 3 server that has a few sites that use the Project Tracking Workspace & IT Team Workspace Site Templates. When I Upgrade the content DBs I get Errors saying:

```
[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [4/7/2014 2:43:47 PM]: Found 2 web(s) using missing web template 75817 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_team.site.com.
[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [4/7/2014 2:43:47 PM]: The site definitions with Id 75817 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_team.site.com], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if necessary.[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [4/7/2014 2:43:47 PM]: Found 120 web(s) using missing web template 75820 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_team.site.com.
[powershell] [SPContentDatabaseSequence] [ERROR] [4/7/2014 2:43:47 PM]: The site definitions with Id 75820 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_team.site.com], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if necessary.
```

Things I've tried:

I have Downloaded the Fab40 Site Templates, Extracted the Project Tracking Workspace & IT Team Workspace templates and globally deployed the solution in the Farm.

In the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML` I can see the two files, `WEBTEMPProjSing.xml` and `WEBTEMPITTeam.xml`, that in them have the template IDs of 75820 and 75817.

I've Downloaded the Templates from TechSolutions:

- [Project Tracking Workspace](http://www.techsolutions.net/ProjectTrackingWorkspace.aspx)
- [IT Team Workspace](http://www.techsolutions.net/ITTeamWorkspace.aspx)

Installed them, globally deployed them, still the same errors.

If I query the Farm for WebTemplates they do not show up. The only time I can get them to show up in the GET-SPWebTemplate is when I deploy the tech solutions solutions to a Specific Web. Though when I do that the Template ID is 1, not the 75820 or 75817

If there was not 120 sites with the Project Tracking Workspace, I would just bag the whole sub site and recreate it. Though That's quote a bit to do for 120 Sites.

To make this even worst, I will then be upgrading these to 2013.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With some additional Google searching I believe I found the issue.

With the Help of [this blog](http://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/sharepoint-2010-upgrade-issue-found-45-webs-using-missing-web-template-75820-lcid-1033-in-contentdatabase/) post I was able to get the two templates I needed installed. Here is the Procedure I followed:

Start a Sharepoint Powershell in Administrator mode. 
Install the ApplicationTemplateCore Solution file

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\Fab40\ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp
```

Wait 5 Minutes, then deploy the solution

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate
```

Wait 5 Minutes, then Copy App Bin Content

```
stsadm -o copyappbincontent
```

Reset the IIS Server

```
iisreset
```

Install the other Solutions that you need with the same commands.

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\Fab40\ ProjectTrackingWorkspace.wsp
```

Wait 5 Minutes, then deploy the solution

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name ProjectTrackingWorkspace.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate
```

Wait 5 Minutes, then Copy App Bin Content

```
stsadm -o copyappbincontent
```

Once you are done adding the Solutions reboot the server.   I used the same commands to do this the first several times, though the Fab 40 Solutions would never be seen or installed.  It must have something to do with the wait time and the resetting IIS and the reboot. That was the only combination that worked for me.